# MongoDB schema and structure

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I just started learning mongoDB and mongoose here.

Is it possible to have value as key in mongoDB? For example, I'd like to have a structure like this:

Person collection:

```
USA: {
  'John Doe': { phone: '...', somethingElse: '...' },
  'Jane Doe': { phone: '...', somethingElse: '...' },
},
Australia: {
  'John Doe': { phone: '...', somethingElse: '...' },
  'Jane Doe': { phone: '...', somethingElse: '...' },
},
England: {
  'John Doe': { phone: '...', somethingElse: '...' },
  'Jane Doe': { phone: '...', somethingElse: '...' },
}
```

I know it's a terrible example, and I understand alternatively we can store the documents like:

```
{_id: 1, name: 'John Doe', address: 'USA', phone: '...', ...},
{_id: 2, name: 'John Doe', address: 'Australia', phone: '...', ...},
{_id: 3, name: 'John Doe', address: 'England', phone: '...', ...},
```

I guess I'm just trying to understand if storing `value` as `key` is even possible here. And if it is, how do we define the schema with mongoose?

Answer (score 1):

**Theoretically** you could use a schema like:

```
const testSchema = new Schema({
    countries: {
        type: Map,
        of: {
            type: Map,
            of: Object,
        },
    },
});
```

taking advantage of [Map](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps) type in mongoose, then you can assign your dynamic object to `contries` property.

Personally I believe that second approach you mentioned is a way better idea (unless you really have a good reason for using the first one).

First reason is that having dynamic key names makes querying difficult. Instead of simple `.find({name: 'John Doe'})` you need to run complicated aggregation queries like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59056504/mongodb-find-documents-matching-certain-condition-for-unknown-field-keys/59056744#59056744). Basically any traversing like counting people, filtering by phone etc will be painful with dynamic keys.

Second reason is that MongoDB document has [16MB limitation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents) so gathering too many people means you can approach that limit.